# Group markers in Open Layers 3.

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I would like to group markers in Open Layer 3. Like this:

[image]

I was looking for some example in internet but I could not found it. 
How can I do it with Open Layers 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some examples that can push you in right direction, for starters you can look here:

1. OpenLayers official example: [Clustered Features](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cluster.html)
2. OpenLayers extension: [Animated Cluster](http://viglino.github.io/OL3-AnimatedCluster/)
3. OpenLayers extension: [Convex Hull](http://viglino.github.io/ol3-ext/examples/map.cluster.convexhull.html)
4. OpenLayers example (OpenLayers 3 Beginner’s Guide): [Cluster GeoJSON Source](https://openlayersbook.github.io/index.html)

and this little snippet as well;

```js
var map = new ol.Map({
    view: new ol.View({
        zoom: 4,
        center: [2152466, 5850795]
    }),
    target: 'js-map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ]
});

// generate random elements
var getRandomInt = function(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};


var features = [];
var numberOfFeatures = 0;

while (numberOfFeatures < 100) {
    var point = new ol.geom.Point([
        getRandomInt(1545862, 2568284),
        getRandomInt(6102732, 7154505)
    ]);

    features.push(new ol.Feature(point));
    numberOfFeatures++;
}


var getStyle = function(feature) {

    var length = feature.get('features').length;
    return [
        new ol.style.Style({

            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: Math.min(
                    Math.max(length * 0.8, 10), 15 
                ),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: [0, 204, 0, 0.6]
                })
            }),
            text: new ol.style.Text({
                text: length.toString(),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'black'
                })
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: [0, 51, 0, 1],
                width: 1
            }),
            font: '26px "Helvetica Neue", Arial'
        })
    ];
};
// https://github.com/Viglino/OL3-AnimatedCluster
var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
    distance: 100,
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: features 
    })
});

// Animated cluster layer
var clusterLayer = new ol.layer.AnimatedCluster({
    source: clusterSource,
    // Use a style function for cluster symbolisation
    style: getStyle
});


map.addLayer(clusterLayer);
```

```css
.map {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.ol-attribution > ul {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Clusters</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.3.3/css/ol.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="js-map" class="map"></div>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.3.2/build/ol.js"></script>
    <!--animated cluster plugin -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Viglino/OL3-AnimatedCluster/gh-pages/interaction/selectclusterinteraction.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Viglino/OL3-AnimatedCluster/gh-pages/layer/animatedclusterlayer.js"></script>
    <script src="clustering.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```